# Attend DEFCON this year, get a free beer from me

Tags: discussion

It's the first annual Security.SE DEFCON meetup! It's your excuse to go this year! DOOO ITTTT

### Update

I have confirmed I'm going to DEFCON this year, but the details are... "fuzzy." I'm arriving by motorcycle and should be there for every day of it, but I'll figure it out as I go.

If you want free booze with the rest of the Security.SE crowd, I'll announce when and where we can meet up via my Twitter account: https://twitter.com/jbferland

Comment: Are any of you at DEFCON?

Answer (score 3):

I'm in! How might we claim this free [as in] beer prize?

Meetup details to be posted later?

Comment: That is correct!